# Log File size is not increasing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I am adding some 2m record in a table with database in Full Recovery but my log file size is not increasing from the default assigned when database was created.What can be the possible reason?

Comment: how are you adding these 2m rows? what is the log file size already? how often the transaction log backs are being taken?

Comment: The Log size was initially 1mb and still its showing 1mb also there is no transaction log backup job is running

Answer (score 0):

One of two things is happening (possibly both):

1. The log file is already sized to be sufficient for the activity that you're putting against it.
2. There are periodic transaction log backups running.

Answer (score 0):

Log size doesn't increase just because there has been a transaction.  It increases because the current log file doesn't have enough free space for the transaction.

In other words, 2-million-row transaction is small enough, and with your backup schedule, the system sees no need to increase the physical log file size.

Why this happens is due to backup.  When a log backup is taken, the log is truncated.  This doesn't mean that the log file will be shrunk.  Rather, the unused space will be freed for future transaction while the physical size remain unchanged.  This is useful because excessive and repeated increase would take up the system resource unnecessarily.  In other words, if your log file is, say 500MB, then it's likely that that's how much space your database typically needs.  So shrinking it to 1 MB only have it quickly grown to 500 MB would be likely to affect performance negatively.

To see this in action, observe the log file information by running `DBCC SQLPERF(Logspace)` in the database you are interested in. INSERT and BACKUP LOG will change the number(s).

Further reading:

[Log Truncation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189085(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Log Size Management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365418(v=sql.105).aspx)